# EditText disappeared after being placed in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

When i placed my edit text into a linear layout to stop it from lagging is disappeared from the app screen and now my app crashes when its launched.(the ending of the code such as /linearLayout> is there it just wont show up on here)
old code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.trucktracker.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continuebtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="clickedContinue"
        android:text="@string/continue_btn"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/btnbackreg"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/legion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="262dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:src="@drawable/legion" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/continuebtn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="162dp"
    android:text="@string/question1"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Phonesignup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/continuebtn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/phonesignup"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/optionselect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Phonesignup"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/question"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:textColor="#b32017"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/question" />
```

new code:

```
<linearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Phonesignup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/phonesignup"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed the wrong tag for opening a LinearLayout.  It should be a capital 'L', not a lowercase 'l'.  Also, you need to set the orientation of a LinearLayout to either vertical or horizontal:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" (or horizontal)
 >
```